# How should I create a new variable with conditions of other variables?

Tags: r

I need some help in creating a new variable. I need to create a 'couple identifier', which gives a unique code for every couple/triple/... in a household. So, I can identify couples.
To do this, I should use 4 variables:

- SERIAL = a unique numeric code for each household
- PERNUM = a unique numeric code for each person
- SPLOC = the numeric code of the spouse in the household, it is equal to the PERNUM code of the spouse
- SPRULE = rules for linking a spouse, numeric code from 00 to 06

To create the couple identifier, I need these conditions:

- SERIAL needs to be equal for these persons in the couples
- SPLOC > 0
- SPLOC = PERNUM
- SPRULE = 01 or 02

[This is an image of how the dataset looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EE3Ub.png)

How should I do this? What method do I use?
Thank you!

Comment: I was already able to do this (dataset:ipumsi_00008_dta):
# true/false code when sploc is greater than zero 
ipumsi_00008_dta <- mutate(ipumsi_00008_dta, sploc_greater_than_zero = sploc>0)
# true/false code when sploc is greater then zero and sprule is equal to 1 or 2
ipumsi_00008_dta <- mutate(ipumsi_00008_dta, rule_union = sploc>0 & sprule==1 | sprule==2)
# making numeric code for true values of rule_couple when serials are equal, so when they are persons of the same household

Comment: => How do I give a unique numeric code for the persons with code 00 when rule_couple = FALSE & higher unique code when rule_couple = TRUE & when their SERIAL numbers are equal?

Comment: Can u `dput(head(ipumsi_00008_dta, 20))` and paste it into th question